# ANT - javac compile failure due to cannot find symbol

Tags: ant, compilation, javac

I'm trying to compile ActionFactory.java file which imports one of my package, RegisterAction.java

Here is the file structure:

/com/masatosan/actions/register/RegisterAction.java

/com/masatosan/redirector/ActionFactory.java

According to the ANT output, I think ANT cannot find RegisterAction.java which is imported in ActionFactory.java

It does compile successfully when I manually run javac on console so this must be some classpath setting that ANT is not looking at.

I know I can add some jar to ANT_HOME/lib but in my case, ANT seems not be able to find ActionRegister.java, not jar or something else. Could anyone help me find out what's wrong?

**ANT script**

```
<project name="CompileMasatosan"  default="main"
    basedir="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan">
    <description>
        masatosan compiler
    </description>

    <!-- this invokes all targets -->
    <target name="main" depends="compileAll" />

     <!-- properties -->
    <property name="srcMasatosan" 
        location="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan" />

    <property name="dest"
    location="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\WEB-INF\classes" />

    <property name="redirectorSrc" location="${srcMasatosan}\redirector" />

     <!-- complie -->
    <target name="compileAll">
        <javac target="1.5" source="1.5" srcdir="${redirectorSrc}" destdir="${dest}" />
    </target>

</project>
```

**Environment Variable**

```
ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.8.1-bin\apache-ant-1.8.1

 CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\P
rogram Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\mail.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib;C:\Program F
iles\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan\actions\register;
```

**ActionFactory.java**

```
package com.masatosan.redirector;
import com.masatosan.actions.register.RegisterAction;

public class ActionFactory {
//some code here...

}
```

**ANT output**

```
C:\apache-ant-1.8.1-bin\javac_masatosan\debug>ant
Buildfile: C:\apache-ant-1.8.1-bin\javac_masatosan\debug\build.xml

compileAll:
    [javac] C:\apache-ant-1.8.1-bin\javac_masatosan\debug\build.xml:47: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.s
ysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan\redirector\ActionFactory.java:1
5: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class RegisterAction
    [javac] location: package com.masatosan.actions.register
    [javac] import com.masatosan.actions.register.RegisterAction;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\src\com\masatosan\redirector\ActionFactory.java:2
4: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class RegisterAction
    [javac] location: class com.masatosan.redirector.ActionFactory
    [javac]             actions.put("POST/process_register.do", new RegisterAction());
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\apache-ant-1.8.1-bin\javac_masatosan\debug\build.xml:47: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are specifying only one "sourcepath" to "javac" - and not both.  Maybe you should do

```
<target name="compileAll">
  <javac target="1.5" source="1.5" destdir="${dest}">
    <src path="${redirectorSrc}"/>
    <src path="${srcMasatosan}"/>
  </javac>    
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Make it point to your exact jar files directory where jars are present
<path id="classpath">
<fileset dir="${main.jar}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
<!-- <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />-->
</path>

----in my case jar files present in ----
<property name="main.jar"     value="jar"/>
```